# How can I safely update a file opened in several places?

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to store opaque "app settings" using Drive.

I was hoping Drive had something like 'parent_rev' (from DropBox API). So that an app can be certain that the file has not changed between the last sync and the current update operation.

Am I out of luck here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no parameter in the update request to make the API behave like when `parent_ref` is different than the latest version.

You have to manage this collision manually by checking if your local revision is the latest after retrieving  the [revision list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/list) of the file; remember to do that before uploading the file.

By default the [update request](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update) has the `newRevision` flag set to true and it will create a new revision for each upload.

Comment: While checking the revision list is helpful, it doesn't avoid a possible race condition w/ two writers trying to update the same file at the same time.

Comment: You'll end up with 2 revision of the file; if changes are so frequent and you need to keep the "client" version updated I think you'll need to use the Realtime API... but I'm still investigation possible alternatives

Answer (score 1):

Store and compare the values of etag. Looking at the revision number is fragile.